# C# override property with child/parent relationship

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, properties

So basically what I want to be able to do is to be able to a single property name space that can be overridden by a child of that property's parent. The practical application here is maintaining a Model/View system. Where the views are derived from the same base view class, however some require a more complex model to perform their function.

I was wondering if there is a best practice pattern for this since my current approach of just hiding variable namespaces seems too messy. Here's some sample pseudo-code of what I mean:

```
public class ParentPropertyType{

public string bar = "bar";

}

public class ChildPropertyType: ParentPropertyType{

public string foo = "foo";

}


public class ChildManager:ParentManager {

public virtual ChildPropertyType PropertyType {get; set;}

}

public class ParentManager{

public override ParentPropertyType PropertyType {get; set;}

}

...

Debug.Log(new ParentManager().PropertyType.foo);
```

Comment: I don´t get your point. If you want to be able to override a member from a base-class, use `virtual` and `override`. What do you mean by "hiding a variable namespace"?

Comment: Apart from this your `ChildManager`-class should use `override`, not your `ParentManager`. Your `ParentManager` is the *base*-class, thus it provides the *base*-implementation, which is makred by `virtual`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Imagine a case where I have two views and two models, the advanced versions inherit the simple versions, and each model/view has a reference to one another. AdvancedView, SimpleView, SimpleModel, and AdvancedModel. 

My goal is in case where an object that is an AdvancedView and has an assigned property of AdvancedModel, that calls a method in SimpleView, that references the model, to reference the AdvancedModel rather than the SimpleModel as would be the case if I was using "new" to hide thing.(1/2)

Comment: This would to do something like calculate the estimated height and width the view should be, due to amount of data that is present in model. 

Where an advanced model may have additional data that would change the outcome of the calculation, but you would still want to call the same named method of GetHeight() or the like on the model.

Comment: You don´t "new" anything in your code. Anyway as mentioned by Nick you can´t change a properties/methods return-type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you should make your `ParentManager`-class generic:

```
public class ChildManager : ParentManager<ChildPropertyType>
{
}

public class ParentManager<T> where T: ParentPropertyType 
{
    public T PropertyType { get; set; }   
}
```

Now you don´t even need `virtual` and `override`, as the property has the correct type depending on the class it is used in. Therefor the following compiles fine, because PropertyType returns an instance of ChildPropertyType:

```
var manager = new ChildManager();
ChildPropertyType c = manager.PropertyType;
```

Comment: Ooooh. I actually think this might work. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Yup, I got the behaviour I desired. Since I was using Unity, and had to have the base objects inherit from Basebehaviour, I took the added step of making a generic interface instead which worked just as well.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, there is no way to override a method and change its return type to a descendant type.  "Sad but true".

If I were you, I would reintroduce (using "new") the method / property to return the desired type.

Comment: "I would reintroduce (using "new")" This usually produces more problems than it solves.

Comment: As usual - it depends. :-)